# Rails: Find elements around the current one in previous collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Building a Video-Gallery the user can jump into a category (where are around 500 videos). 
If he clicks one, it will be the show_action.  There we wan't to display also the 2 Videos before and after that selected one, in the previous selection of the category.

I had a working solution, but i'm not sure if this is efficient or if there are any other workarounds?

```
def show
  @category = Videothek::Category.find_by_slug! params[:category]
  @video = @category.videos.find_by_slug params[:slug]

  # TODO
  # @category.videos must be filtered by users previous selection (stored in session)
  arr = @category.videos.select(:id).collect{|x| x.id}
  ids = arr[arr.find_index(@video.id)-2 .. arr.find_index(@video.id)+2] #-2 -1 X +1 +2 (Range of Videos) 
  @videos_around = @category.videos.where(id: ids) || []
 end
```

It is working so far, but I have no idea how it will perform if there are 1500 videos inside a category and we always select ALL Ids, just to find 4 other ones.

any ideas?

// edit:
and in addition, those 5 videos will be displayed in a horizontal slider - so then i need to be able to click to the right and load more videos (of the right side) or the same with the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allright, finally did it

```
#@video and @category loaded by before_filter
def related
  @videos = related_videos(@video, params[:page].to_i)
  render json: {videos: @videos.as_json}
end
```

So then we want to archive this scenariox

```
# Example Tabeele
# index = 11
#
#     page -2          page -1           START              page +1          page +2  
#            |         +         |         X        |          +        |              
# [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]




private


  def related_videos(video, page=0)
    # get all ids of videos in category
    arr = @category.videos.pluck(:id)

    # less as 5 => page 0 is all
    if arr.length <= 5
      return @category.videos.where(ids: arr)
    end

    index = arr.find_index(video.id)

    #transform index if we are first 2 or last 2 items
    index = 2  if index == 0 || index == 1
    index = arr.length - 3 if index == arr.length-1 || index == arr.length-2

    # new ids
    ids = []

    if page == 0
      ids = arr[0..4] if index <=2
      ids = arr[-5..-1] if index >= arr.length-2
      if ids == []
        ids = arr[index-2..index+2]
      end   
    end


    # Pagination
    offset = page * 5 # -10, -5  oder +5 +10 
    new_index = index + offset

    # to rhe right
    if page > 0 
      if new_index-2 >= arr.size
        ids = [] # no more videos :()
      else
        if new_index+2 >= arr.size
          ids = arr[new_index-2 .. -1]
        else
          ids = arr[new_index-2 .. new_index+2]
        end
      end
    end

    # to the left
    if page < 0 
      if new_index + 2 < 0
        ids = [] 
      else
        if new_index < 2
          ids = arr[0..new_index+2]
        else
          ids = arr[new_index-2 .. new_index+2] 
        end
      end
    end

    return @category.videos.where(id: ids)
  end
```

This now is returning exactly what it should, based on the example table :-)

maybe it will help somebody

Answer (score 1):

One obvious improvement is to use [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method to collect the ids.

Here is the improved code:

```
ids_array = @category.videos.pluck(:id)
current_video_index = ids_array.index(@video.id)
start_index = current_video_index - 2
end_index = current_video_index + 2
ids = ids_array[start_index..end_index] # -2 -1 X +1 +2 (Range of Videos)
@videos_around = @category.videos.where(id: ids) || []
```

#### More update (Railsy/Cleaner way):

You can get the next and previous two videos of the current `@video` using Active Record:

```
@category.videos.where('id > ?', @video.id).first(2) # gives next two videos of the current video
@category.videos.where('id < ?', @video.id).last(2) # gives previous two videos of the current video
```

#### Update

If you already had scopes defined on it, you can use [reorder](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/reorder) first to replace any existing order and then do the following:

```
@category.videos.reorder(id: :asc).where('id > ?', @video.id).first(2) # gives next two videos of the current video
@category.videos.reorder(id: :asc).where('id < ?', @video.id).last(2) # gives previous two videos of the current video
```

Comment: @huanson Look at my updated code and see if you like it now!

Comment: well the ID stuff is not working, since the user can set his own filters (sort by best rating etc.). that would be the easiest implementation :-)

Comment: Well, If you already had scopes defined on it, you can use reorder first to replace any existing order and then do the above. See my updated answer.